# automatically forward emails using gmail api?

Tags: c#, email, google-api, gmail-api

I am trying to create a program that whenever a certain email receives mail it will automatically forward it on to another person (a whatsapp account to be specific but I'm not to that stage in the program yet.) I am currently just working with the gmail api mostly because the email that will be the one receiving mail is a gmail account.

I have gotten the program working well enough to send plain text that I have typed into the code itself, but am unsure really where to begin with retrieving and forwarding emails that are incoming to my mailbox. Google's documentation isn't the most helpful since I'm coding in C# and they don't have a lot of info when it comes to that.

*So long story short I want to get and forward emails to another gmail account (for now) and need some help figuring out how using the gmail api and c#.*

I have tried reading through google's documentation as well as looking at what others have done and none of it really seems correct for what I'm trying to do? Below you'll see the code I have already got that is working to send an email based on what I write in plaintext.

`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;


namespace WhatsApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailSend };
        static string[] ScopeM = { GmailService.Scope.GmailModify };
        static string ApplicationName = "Gmail API";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
            new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open,
              FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = "token_Send.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                             GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                              Scopes,
                              "user",
                              CancellationToken.None,
                              new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            
            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

                      
            string plainText = "To:*********@gmail.com\r\n" +
                             "Subject: Test\r\n" +
                             "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\r\n\r\n" +
                             "<h1>Test2<h1>";

            var newMsg = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message();
            newMsg.Raw = Program.Base64UrlEncode(plainText.ToString());
            service.Users.Messages.Send(newMsg, "me").Execute();
            Console.Read();

        }

        private static string Base64UrlEncode(string input)
        {
            var inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            
            return Convert.ToBase64String(inputBytes)
              .Replace('+', '-')
              .Replace('/', '_')
              .Replace("=", "");

        }
    }
}
```

`

I changed the email I'm using to ** just so that I'm not posting emails that I don't want posted, but everything else is unchanged and working.
Any help on how to make this code get emails as they come in and forward them would be great!

Comment: Why not just configure forwarding under settings [updateAutoForwarding](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings/updateAutoForwarding)

Comment: I don't want to just change the settings since down the line I will be sending to something that is not an email address and thus couldn't be forwarded to in auto forwarding settings (I don't think). In this instance I just need help forwarding to an email as a base for future code. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: In that case it really sounds like you will have to manually list the incoming emails and then again manually send the email to the desired email address, since you can't use the autoforwarding method it really looks like you will have to manually perform the lookup of the emails that matches your criteria. For example, you can use the [users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) method and make a query based on a certain word of phrase depending on your criteria and then use the regular send method that you were using.